# ASWebAuthenticationSession w/ SwiftUI

Tags: authentication, swiftui, openid-connect, aswebauthenticationsession

Recently, I implemented an `ASWebAuthenicationSession` in my SwiftUI application to handle the OIDC Authentication of my app. My question is:  Is it possible to change the size of the Safari login view that pops up to handle the `ASWebAuthenticationSession`?  I am looking to make the window a bit larger than the default.

This link includes the pattern I followed.

[Using ASWebAuthenticationSession with SwiftUI](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/using-aswebauthenticationaession-swiftui/)

Above pattern and works as expected. Looking to increase size of login window.